# backbone memory leak remove not working?

Tags: backbone.js, memory-leaks

In the router I do this

```
            function test()  {
                self.topbarView = new TopbarView();
                self.topbarView.render();
                GhostviewHunter.addView(self.topbarView);
            }

            function clean() {
                console.log(GhostviewHunter.currentViews.length);
                GhostviewHunter.clean();
            }
            setInterval(test, 1000);
            setInterval(clean, 1000);
```

ghostviewhunter should clean/remove the views:

```
define('ghostviewHunter', [], function() {

    var GhostviewHunter = function() {};

    GhostviewHunter.prototype.currentViews = [];

    GhostviewHunter.prototype.addView = function(view) {
        this.currentViews.push(view);
    }

    GhostviewHunter.prototype.clean = function() {
        _.each(this.currentViews, function(view) {
            view.remove();
        });
        this.currentViews.length = 0;
    }

    GhostviewHunter.__instance = null;

    GhostviewHunter.getInstance = function() {
        if( GhostviewHunter.__instance == null ) {
            GhostviewHunter.__instance = new GhostviewHunter();
        } 
        return GhostviewHunter.__instance;
    }

    return GhostviewHunter.getInstance();

})
```

TopView is fetching a model, the model is updated every 1seconde with setInterval function.

I thought that remove(); would be enough be the memory leak is very quick when I monitor the app.

Any idea ?

EDIT:
TOPBARVIEW

```
define('topbarView', [
    'backbone',
    'parameterManager',
    'text!views/topbarView/topbarTemplate.html',
    'drupalidModel',
    'weatherModel',
    'refreshTime',
    'dateParser'
    ], function(Backbone, ParameterManager, TopbarTemplate, DrupalidModel, WeatherModel, RefreshTime, DateParser) {

    var TopbarView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#topbar',

        template: _.template(TopbarTemplate),

        events: {},

        initialize: function() {
            var self = this;
            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'startDateRefresh');
            this.dateParser = new DateParser();
            self.startDateRefresh();
            setInterval(self.startDateRefresh, RefreshTime.date);
            this.initWeatherModel();        
        },

        render: function() {
            var self = this;
            var data = {
                picto_url : ParameterManager.get('WEATHER_RESOURCE_URL') + ParameterManager.get('WEATHER_PICTO_CODE') + ".png",
                date: self.date
            }
            this.$el.html(this.template({data: data}));
        },

        initWeatherModel: function() {
            var self = this;
            var weather_url = ParameterManager.get('WEATHER_URL');

            if(weather_url === null) {
                this.drupalidModel = new DrupalidModel();
                this.drupalidModel.fetch({
                    success: function(model, response) {
                        var center_id_num = model.get('center_id_num');
                        ParameterManager.set('DRUPAL_CENTER_ID_NUM', center_id_num);
                        ParameterManager.constructWeatherUrl();
                        self.model = new WeatherModel();
                        self.listenTo(self.model,'change', self.render);
                        self.startModelRefresh();
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log("Failed to fetch center id!");
                    }
                })
            } else {
                this.model = new WeatherModel();
                self.listenTo(self.model,'change', self.render);
                this.startModelRefresh();
            };
        },

        startModelRefresh: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.modelRefresh = function() {
                self.model.fetch();
            }.bind(this);
            self.modelRefresh();
            setInterval(self.modelRefresh, RefreshTime.weather);        
        },

        stopModelRefresh: function() {
            var self = this;
            clearInterval( self.modelRefresh );
        },

        startDateRefresh: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.date = this.dateParser.classicDate();
            this.render();
        }

    });

    return TopbarView;

})
```

Comment: What is in `topbarView`..? Can you create an [mcve]?

Comment: I guess this is due to a bad management of set interval but I can't figure out clearly whats i've done wrong

Comment: I second T J's request for an MCVE. In the Chrome developer tools use Timeline to monitor the memory usage and press `Collect garbage` (usually a trash can icon) regulary and especially before and after calling `clean()`. Isolate if and what type of memory leaks. Add this to your post. Note that the memory leak might not be caused by Backbone misuse but also by a trivial closure leak.

Comment: You are starting many `setInterval`'s without properly clearing them, in `startModelRefresh`. `setInterval` returns an id that is used for `clearInterval`. As it stands, in `stopModelRefresh`, you are passing `clearInterval` a function reference. I would start by fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

As fbynite suggested, your code which is supposed to clear the interval(s) is not correct, you should pass the interval id to `clearInterval`.

apart from that, you're not calling `stopModelRefresh()` at all. You should make sure all external references are properly removed before removing the view. For example I've added a destroy method that clears the interval before removing the view:

```js
var TopbarView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#topbar',
  template: _.template(TopbarTemplate),
  events: {},
  initialize: function() {
  },
  render: function() {
  },
  modelRefresh: function() {
    this.model.fetch();
  },
  startModelRefresh: function() {
    this.modelRefresh();
    this.intervalId = setInterval(_.bind(this.modelRefresh,this), RefreshTime.weather);
  },
  stopModelRefresh: function() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  },
  destroy: function() {
    this.stopModelRefresh();
    this.remove();
  }

});
```

Now your `GhostviewHunter` should call it instead of directly calling `remove`:

```
GhostviewHunter.prototype.clean = function() {
   _.each(this.currentViews, function(view) {
            view.destroy();
   });
   this.currentViews.length = 0;
}
```

or you can even override the `remove` method itself to something like:

```
remove: function(){
  this.stopThisInterval();
  this.stopThatInterval();
  this.cleanUpSomethingElse();
  Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
}
```

and have the ghost thingy call `remove` itself.

---

Note that you have other interval calling `startDateRefresh` which you're not even attempting to clear... You should clear all such similarly.

And as a side note, I strongly suggest to stop spamming `self = this` where it is totally unnecessary for eg:

```
stopModelRefresh: function() {
        var self = this;
        clearInterval( self.modelRefresh );
 // Why..? Nothing here changes the context?
},
```

and I also suggest recursively calling `modelRefresh` once the current fetch succeeds/fails rather than calling it from an interval where you have no guarantee that the previous fetch is complete